# How to mock out InetAddress.getLocalHost() using JMockit

Tags: jmockit

The InetAddress constructor is not visible because the factory pattern is used.

```
final InetAddress anyInstance = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    new NonStrictExpectations(InetAddress.class) {
      {
        anyInstance.getHostAddress();
        result = "192.168.0.101";
      }
    };
```

When I try to use the factory method to get an instance for partial mocking I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing invocation to mocked type at this point; please make sure such invocations appear only after the declaration of a suitable mock field or parameter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that `InetAddress` *and* any subclasses should be mocked:

```
@Test
public void mockAnyInetAddress(@Capturing final InetAddress anyInstance)
    throws Exception
{
    new Expectations() {{
        anyInstance.getHostAddress(); result = "192.168.0.101";
    }};

    String localHostAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();

    assertEquals("192.168.0.101", localHostAddress);
}
```

Comment: It looks like it is not correctly partially mocking when combined with Capturing. When I run your exact code I get:
  mockit.internal.UnexpectedInvocation: Unexpected invocation of: java.net.InetAddress#getLocalHost()

If I set it as a NonStrictExpectations I get a null pointer exception because getLocalHost returns null. I am using JMockit 1.8 which looks to be a year old. I will see if a newer version fixes it

Comment: looks like it was an issue with 1.8. it works fine in 1.17. not sure which version it was fixed in. Thanks for your help!